# Cannot open both root terminal and nautilus (in Debian 7) after updating Intel Graphics Driver

Tags: linux, debian, grub, gnome-terminal, intel-graphics

I bought a laptop (Asus, i686 architecture) only with pre-installed Debian 7. However, then I found that when I moved mouse horizontally, the screen shakes horizontally as well. Therefore I decided to update Intel Graphics Driver (before I was making updating, I installed `KDE` Plasma 5 for my system).

After updating, my desktop environment automatically returned back to `GNOME` (`KDE` has been automatically uninstalled, I don't know why). Unfortunately, I found that I can not open either the root terminal or nautilus in `GNOME`, as I click on it, the interface will show up for no more than 1 second and then shut down.

So how can I fix this problem? Do I need to recover Debian using GRUB, if so, how can I do that?

Comment: I have installed the backport of Intel Graphics Driver for Debian Wheezy and I reboot the machine. Here jumped out the following message: **Warning: Cannot open ConsoleKit session: Unable to open session: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory** And I pressed "OK" button under this message. Then it came out **Oh no! Something has gone wrong." and "A problem has occurred and the system can't recover. Please log out and try again.**

Answer (score 0):

Using Synaptic package manager search `kde-plasma-desktop` and install it

reboot

Answer (score 0):

When installing new packages, check carefully what packages will be uninstalled.

Where did you find the updated Intel graphic drivers?  Possibly the package is not made for Debian, so it messed the libraries, and forced uninstall of important components.  If the package is not from Debian, I suggest you to remove it, and try to solve the problem with Debian packages. Possibly there is a missing package or an error in configuration.

`apt-get remove the-non-debian-driver`

`apt-get install kde-standard`

But now: how to get a root prompt:

- Try any terminal (e.g. xterm) available, and then type `su` (give us the error message)
- If you don't have any working terminal, press `Control-Alt-F2`, and it will give a console terminal.  Just log in as root, and install the missing packages. `Alt-F6` or `Alt-F7` (or try other Alt-Fx combination) will bring you back to graphic interface.  But possible a `reboot` command is better.
- As last possibility, you can get to GRUB the additional parameter: `single`, which will boot Debian in a recovery mode, without starting the graphical interface.

Comment: [Updating the Intel graphics driver on Debian stable](https://www.slightfuture.com/how-to/debian-newer-intel-graphics) -- I was updating Intel Graphics Driver following the instructions on this link.  One thing might be done in a wrong way: I uncommented all the links in /etc/apt/sources.list @GiacomoCatenazzi

Comment: Mixing Debian distributions (stable and testing) often cause conflicts. Note that the same version is provided by debian backports ( https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/xserver-xorg-video-intel ). Backports don't have conflicts, because they are new sources compiled with the stable libraries.